# Unable to use curl and service name from inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am running **kubernetes single node on coreos**.

I have created a pod running a python application and exposing an http endpoint.

I have created a kubernetes service that exposes the HTTP endpoint. I have exposed this service using NodePort and can call it successfully from outside the cluster.

What I am then trying is to call the HTTP service from a docker container. To test I am just using the same running container and using curl.

I can `docker exec` into the docker container running my service.
nslookup for 'my-service' resolves to an IP address. So I am happy that **DNS service registration is working correctly**. (I have also checked that the ENV variables for the service exist - and they do and are the same as the value returned from `nslookup`)

However, if I then try:

```
curl http://my-service:9042/status
```

It just hangs with no response. (Port 9042 is the correct port and status is a valid resource)

I'm assuming that I'm missing something really obvious. Any suggestions warmly received.

Update:

The response of curl -v is:

```
root@lake-cluster-manager:/# curl -v http://lake-service:9042/status
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.3.0.128...
```

The output from nslookup is:

```
root@lake-cluster-manager:/# nslookup lake-service   
Server:     10.3.0.10
Address:    10.3.0.10#53

Name:   lake-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.3.0.128
```

Comment: Please, share with us an output from the following command:

`curl -v http://my-service:9042/status`

Comment: Thanks @IDvoretskyi I have added the curl -v info and also the output from nsloookup to the original description.

Comment: @IDvoretskyi  I think I found the problem. The container I was testing the curl command from was the one hosting the service. If I started another container on the same node in another Pod the curl command worked as expected. I would like to understand why this was the case...

Comment: @gra-moore Did you figure out anything

Comment: @RajeshRajendran did you find out why a container can't reference itself by its service name? I am running an IdentityServer that needs to be able to reference itsself by service name and when it does, it times out. I connected to the pod with kubectl and tried  to curl to its service name which just hangs.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, it sounds like you got this to work.

Traffic to service IPs is forwarded via kube-proxy, either through a user-space proxy or through iptables rules, depending on the Kubernetes release version and configuration. You may want to look at the iptables rules for the node corresponding to that container to see if that could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

since Kubernetes v1.10 `kubectl port-forward` allows using resource name, such as a service name, to select a matching pod to port forward 
With this connection in place you can use your local workstation to debug the application that is running in the pod.

capture your pod PORT NUMBER

```
kubectl get pods [YOUR_PODE_NAME] --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}'
```

let's say we got PORT NUMBER 8080

```
kubectl port-forward [YOUR_PODE_NAME] 8080:8080
```

Now Navigate to http://localhost:8080/ on your local machine to see your application running

Answer (score 1):

Another way to reach a service on another pod in the same cluster is using the extended network name of the service, like:

```
service-name: wash-disher
service-port: 8080
namespace: restaurant

kubectl run client --image=curlimages/curl --namespace test
kubectl -n test exec client-654845585c-s4fcw -- curl -v -Ss http://wash-disher.restaurant.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

You can find it through nslookup on the service ip:

```
$ kubectl -n test exec client-654845585c-s4fcw -- nslookup 10.96.183.177
Server:         10.96.5.5
Address:        10.96.5.5:53

a.b.c.d.in-addr.arpa      name = ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

this took me around 30 minutes - 1 hour. So in order to save y'all time, all you might need to care about is the port in the service. For me, I mistakenly keep curl into the app port, but in fact we should have curl into the service:port. Here is an example

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
         - containerPort: 3000 # (Assumption only) - assume your app run at port 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9999 # <--- ** this is what we need to look at **
      targetPort: 3000
```

So instead of curl nginx-service:3000, the correct one is nginx-service:9999. You can test this out by:

```
kubectl -n default run tmp-shell --rm -i --tty --image nicolaka/netshoot -- /bin/bash
```

and run the following to test:

```
tmp-shell:~# nslook up app1-service
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   app1-service.demo.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.109.78.150

tmp-shell:~# curl app1-service:9991
Hello from app1
```